# Transform.Find sends null value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject

I am making a simple deck/card project. My project has a card prefab, with a Canvas child which would contain the UI version of the suit/card information. The information can be displayed with one card, but has problems when it comes to multiple cards. My theory on the matter is due to GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(string) finds the first instance of the gameObject that holds the tag. So, when I draw multiple cards, it will just rewrite the first card, rather than draw on the other cards.

I have tried Transform.Find(string), but it has turned up null, despite having a game object set in the Editor. One solution would be to use multiple tags with numbers after the name, ala topNum1, topNum2, etc., but doing that for 52 different numbers 3 times each sounds very repetitive, and frustrating. Is there a better way to do this?

Card code below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

/// <summary>
/// This class sets up the card object, which can be used in a variety of games.
/// </summary>

public class Card: MonoBehaviour
{

int cardNum;//The Value of the card.
int cardType;//The ‘Suit’ of the card. Hearts, Spades, Diamonds, Clubs
//Text topText;
Text botText;
Text faceText;
Text topText;

//Creates a default card.
public Card()
{
    cardNum = -1;
    cardType = -1;
    topText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("topText").GetComponent<Text>();
    //topText = gameObject.transform.FindChild("Canvas").gameObject.transform.FindChild("TopCardValue").GetComponent<Text>();
    botText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("botText").GetComponent<Text>();
    faceText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("faceText").GetComponent<Text>();
}
//Creates a custom card, with the provided values.
public Card(int cN, int cT)
{
    cardNum = cN;
    cardType = cT;
    topText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("topText").GetComponent<Text>();
    //topText = gameObject.transform.FindChild("Canvas").gameObject.transform.FindChild("TopCardValue").GetComponent<Text>();
    botText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("botText").GetComponent<Text>();
    faceText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("faceText").GetComponent<Text>();
}

//returns the card’s value.
public int getCardNum()
{
    return cardNum;
}

//returns the card’s suit.
public int getCardType()
{
    return cardType;
}

//Sets the card’s value.
public void setCardNum(int newNum)
{
    cardNum = newNum;
}

//Sets the card’s suit.
public void setCardType(int newType)
{
    cardType = newType;
}

//Checks if the card’s value is a face card (Jack, Queen, King, or Ace)
public bool checkIfFace()
{
    if (getCardNum() > 10 && getCardNum() < 15 || getCardNum() == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

//Checks if the card is a valid card.
public bool checkifValid()
{
    if (getCardType() < -1 || getCardType() > 4)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error: Card Type not valid. Card type is: " + getCardType());
        return false;
    }
    if (getCardNum() < 0 || getCardNum() > 15)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error: Card Value not valid. Card value is : " + getCardNum());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
//Prints out the card information.
public void printOutCardInfo()
{
    string value = "";
    string suit = "";


    if (getCardNum() == 1)
        value = (" Ace");
    else if (getCardNum() > 1 && getCardNum() < 11)
        value = (getCardNum().ToString());
    else if (getCardNum() == 11)
       value = ("Jack");
    else if (getCardNum() == 12)
       value = ("Queen");
    else if (getCardNum() == 13)
       value = ("King");
    else
        Debug.LogError("Error: No Num Found! The number in question is: " + getCardNum());
    switch(getCardType())
    {
        case 0:
            suit = ("Hearts");
            break;
        case 1:
            suit = ("Spades");
            break;
        case 2:
            suit = ("Diamonds");
            break;
        case 3:
            suit = ("Clubs");
            break;
        default:
            Debug.LogError("Error: Suit not found.");
            break;
    }
    topText.text = value;
    botText.text = value;
    faceText.text = suit;
}
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Since a few people asked for it, I have edited this question to include the code that this class is called in:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ListDeck : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Card[] deckOfCards;
    List<Card> deckOfCards;

   // public GameObject spawner;
    //public GameObject card;

    //The default constructor.
    public ListDeck()
    {
        deckOfCards = new List<Card>();
        setUpDeck(4, 14);
        randomizeDeck();
    }

    //Sets up the deck
    public void setUpDeck(int numSuits, int numValues)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < numValues; i++)//the thirteen values.
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numSuits; j++)//The four suits. 
            {
                Debug.Log("I value: " + i + " j value: " + j);
                deckOfCards.Add(new Card(i, j));
                counter++;//Increments the counter.
            }
        }
    }
    //Randomizes the deck so that the card dealout is random.
    //http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/486626/how-can-i-shuffle-alist.html
    public void randomizeDeck()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < deckOfCards.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(i);
            Card temp = deckOfCards[i];
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(i, deckOfCards.Count);
            deckOfCards[i] = deckOfCards[randomIndex];
            deckOfCards[randomIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
    //Prints out the deck for the game.
    public void printOutDeck()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < deckOfCards.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("Card " + i + ": ");
            deckOfCards[i].printOutCardInfo();
        }
    }

    public List<Card> getDeck()
    {
        return deckOfCards;
    }

    public void transferCards(List<Card> deckTo, int numCards)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++)
        {
            deckTo.Add(deckOfCards[0]);
            deckOfCards.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1. Is your `Card` script attached to a GameObject? 2. How is it being called from another script?

Comment: 1. It is being attached to a GameObject. That is why I tried using transform.Find(). 2. I have posted the other script, the one that calls the code from the Card Script.

Comment: Ok. Good. I think I found your problem. May I asked what Unity version are you using?

Comment: 5.3.4f1 Personal.

Comment: By looking at your code, you don't seem like a beginner in programming. Maybe you are new to Unity? In this case I suggest you watch the [basics](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting) video. They are very important to understand before you continue doing serious stuff.  Take a look at my answer. I suggest you read them all because you are making lots of mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are calling the Unity API functions from a constructor function. Basically, you are doing this during deserialization and in another `Thread`.

In **Unity 5.3.4f1** and below, the `Find` function will silently fail when called from a constructor and you won't know. This is one of the mistakes that is complicated to track in Unity.

In **Unity 5.4** and above, Unity [decided](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/06/06/serialization-monobehaviour-constructors-and-unity-5-4/) to add error message to alert you about this problem. You won't see it now because you are still using **5.3**. The error is as fellow:

> FindGameObjectWithTag is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour
>   constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start
>   instead. Called from MonoBehaviour 'Card' on game object 'Cube'.

Similar error message will appear when the `Find` function is called in a constructor function.

**Continue reading for more descriptive information and solution**:

### Inheriting from `MonoBehaviour` vs not inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`

**Inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`**:

**1**.You can attach the script to a GameObject.

**2**.You can't use the `new` keyword to create a new instance of a script that inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. Your `deckOfCards.Add(new Card(i, j));` is wrong in this case since `Card` inherits from `MonoBehaviour`.

3.You use `gameobject.AddComponent<Card>()` or the `Instantiate`(clone prefab) function to create new instance of script. There is an example at the end of this.

**Rules for using a constructor function in Unity**:

**1**.Do not use a constructor in a script that inherits from `MonoBehaviour` unless you understand what's going on under the hood in Unity.

**2**.If you are going to use a constructor, do not inherit the script from `MonoBehaviour`.

**3**.If you break Rule #2, do not use any Unity API in a constructor function of a class that inherits from `MonoBehaviour`.

**Why?**

You cannot call Unity API from another Thread. It will fail. You will either get an exception or it will silently fail.

**What does this have to do with Threads?**

A constructor function is called from another `Thread` in Unity.

When a script is attached to a GameObject and that script inherits from `MonoBehaviour` and has a constructor, that constructor is first called from Unity's main Thread(which is fine) then it is called again from **another** `Thread` (non Unity's main `Thread`). This breaks rule **#3**. You cannot use Unity API from another function.

You can prove this by running the code below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;

public class Card : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Card()
    {
        Debug.Log("Constructor Thread ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Start() function Thread ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Update() function Thread ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

**Output when attached to a GameObject**:

> Constructor Thread ID: 1
>
> Constructor Thread ID: 20
>
> Start() function Thread ID 1
>
> Update() function Thread ID: 1

As you can see, the `Start()` and `Update()` functions are called from the-same `Thread` (**ID 1**)which is the main `Thread`. The Constructor function is also called from the main `Thread` but then called again from another `Thread` (**ID 20**).

**Example of BAD code**: Because there is a constructor in a script that inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. Also bad because new instance is created with the `new` keyword.

```
public class Card : MonoBehaviour
{
    Text topText;

   //Bad, because  `MonoBehaviour` is inherited
    public Card()
    {
        topText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("topText").GetComponent<Text>();
    }
}
```

then creating new instance with the `new` keyword:

`Card card = new Card();` //Bad, because `MonoBehaviour` is inherited

**Example of Good code:**

```
public class Card : MonoBehaviour
{
    Text topText;

    public Awake()
    {
        topText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("topText").GetComponent<Text>();
    }
}
```

then creating new instance with the `AddComponent` function:

`Card card = gameObject.AddComponent<Card>()`

OR clone from prefab with the `Instantiate` function:

```
public Card cardPrfab;
Card card = (Card)Instantiate(cardPrfab);
```

**Not inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`**:

**1**.You can't attach the script to a GameObject but you can use it from another script.

**2**.You can simply use the `new` keyword to create new instance of the script when it doesn't inherit from `MonoBehaviour`.

```
public class Card
{
    Text topText;
    //Constructor

   //Correct, because no `MonoBehaviour` inherited
    public Card()
    {
        topText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("topText").GetComponent<Text>();
    }
}
```

Then you can create new instance with the `new` keyword like:

`Card card = new Card();` //Correct, because no `MonoBehaviour` inherited

Solution:

**1**.If you decide to inherit from `MonoBehaviour` and have to attach the script to a GameObject , you must **remove** all your constructor functions and put code inside them into `Awake()` or `Start()` function. The `Awake()` and `Start()` functions are automatically called by Unity once and you use them initialize your variables. You don't have to call them manually. Do **not** use the `new` keyword to create instance of scripts that inherit from `MonoBehaviour`.

**2**.If you decide **not** to inherit from `MonoBehaviour` and you are **not** required to attach the script to a GameObject, you can have a constructor function like you did in your current code and you can use Unity's API in those constructor functions.You can now use `new` keyword to create instance of the script since it doesn't inherit from `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comprehensive answer.
.
I will take a long hard look at my code over the next few days, and figure out my next course of action. I am leaning towards the first option, and will work to edit my code to reflect that. Believe it or not, while the explicit error was added in 5.4, there are several other errors that should've ticked me off to this problem. I apologize for not noticing/acting on them before.

Comment: That's fine. I think it is more helpful to explain your problem than just drop an answer because it will help you solve other problems in your code too. If you fix the errors mentioned and still have problems, you can create a new question with your **new** modified code then notify me here. I will be more than happy to take a look at it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the code and question, every card gets it's text from one and the same GameObject as all of them are searching for the same Object by text.
I believe your issue might be resolved if you actually initialize the values you want to get, in the Start() method of each object.

Thus in reverse for drawing cards, every gameObject that is beeing drawn receives the same text.

And as stated in the answer quicker than me, try not to use Find() as it get's really slow when it comes to more cards or even just objects.

Try setting the text to display from a Start() method inside of a script on the prefab, then you have easy access to all properties of that object and if needed a database of all cards from where you can reference the text to draw.

Might be that I am completely wrong on what you're asking however.
This is just how I would do it, since you said all help is welcome :)

Comment: I have tried setting the values from a Start() method rather than the constructors. The thing is, when I have done this, the start method is not called. as Start is not a public method, and thus cannot be called from outside methods. I use the constructor to not only set up the UI elements, but the values of the card elements as well. So, with the way the code is right now, I do not think it is a very viable solution. I could be wrong, though. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Transform.Find()/Transform.FindChild() is searching **direct CHILD**.
I believe, you trying to find some subChild, that's why its returns null.

So if you have to find "heart" gameObject that have location: room/human/body/heart
inside of "room" element, you need to perform:

```
Transform.Find("human/body/heart")
```

but not

```
Transform.Find("heart")
```

as "heart" is not subChild of "room" game object

Comment: This is not the problem. It should be able to find it without doing that. Even findbytag is failing on his side too. This is something complicated...

Comment: I have no reason to think that is more complicated that this:) I didn't saw his objects hierarchy, I don't sure that tags correctly attached, etc :)

Comment: I keep confusing GameObject.Find with Transform.Find. Anyways, I see may serious problems in his code. I will alert you when I drop an answer.

Comment: Ok Andrew. Read the first 6 lines of my answer. That's what OP is going through. Most people don't know this. You can read the rest if you want too. You will learn a-lot.